# Strange behaviour of variable name with double underscores

Tags: python

The following code shows no error.

```
class Bar():
    pass

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__bar = Bar()

    def get_bar(self):
        return self.__bar

foo = Foo()
bar1 = foo.get_bar()

foo.__bar = Bar()
bar2 = foo.get_bar()

assert (bar1 is bar2)
```

Why is __bar acting like a singleton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because double underscores [are magical](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private): Python mangles these names so that they can't be accessed from outside the class.

If you were to replace the last three lines of your example with...

```
foo._Foo__bar = Bar()
bar2 = foo.get_bar()

assert (bar1 is bar2)
```

...you would see the behavior you expect.

Comment: or if you implemented a `set_bar` method which sets `self.__foo`.

Comment: To emphasize what Daniel said in his comment, implementing a `set_bar` method is the correct way to do it.  The example in this answer was just to demonstrate the name mangling.